# Safe to install vinyl plank flooring over existing peel and stick

Tags: flooring

Looking for some insight on best approach for prepping a floor for vinyl plank install.
I am laying down vinyl plank flooring in our laundry room/mud room. I was going to remove the two layers of peel and stick flooring first. A contractor coming in to liquors painting kitchen cabinets mentioned he would just put it over the peel and stick.
My instincts are to remove all existing peel and stick. But my wife says I have a tendency to make projects bigger than they need to be. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating floors like that were developed specifically to avoid the need to remove the flooring underneath in most cases. if your existing flooring is well bonded and flat, there's no need to take it up unless you have height transition issues with adjacent rooms.

To be absolutely sure, and to avoid compromising your warranty, read the product literature.

Comment: So removing the top layer of peel and stick is Alli need to do?

Comment: No, if the floor is flat and no tiles are peeling up, the new floor will 'float' over the tiles. I would put rosin paper (or something like it) down first so there the new floor won't stick to the existing tiles.